# View Column length Changed,when created with case and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

View column length (Postcode) has increased to varchar(8000)!, when created from the underlying table, it's column length is only varchar(8)

Database is SQL Server 2012.

```
create view v_testing as
    select Postcode = CASE WHEN LEN(A.RealPostcode) = 0 THEN NULL
                           ELSE REPLACE(A.RealPostcode,' ','')
                      END,
           A.RealPostcode
    from dbo.Table A;
```

Comment: Why do you care about the length?  It doesn't really affect anything.

Comment: Seems like `replace` always has return type varchar(8000), when varchar input. More or less ANSI SQL defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

> If string_expression is not of type varchar(max) or
>   nvarchar(max),REPLACE truncates the return value at 8,000 bytes. To
>   return values greater than 8,000 bytes, string_expression must be
>   explicitly cast to a large-value data type.

So just use `cast` function:

```
create view v_testing as
    select Postcode = CASE WHEN LEN(A.RealPostcode) = 0 THEN NULL
                           ELSE CAST(REPLACE(A.RealPostcode,' ','') AS VARCHAR(8))
                      END,
           A.RealPostcode
    from dbo.Table A;
```